# onkeydown='return (window.event.keyCode doesn't allow select input with mouse click

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 5 web page with .NET Framework 4.5.1 and C#.

I have this code:

```
<input type="text" class="quantity"
  name="Quantity" 
  id="Quantity"
  onkeydown='return (window.event.keyCode >= 48 && window.event.keyCode <= 57) || window.event.keyCode == 8 || window.event.keyCode == 46'
  required />
```

`onkeydown` works fine to allow only numbers, backspace and delete keys, but I can't select the input text when I click on it my the mouse.

I haven't found any relative information about this on Internet. Any idea?

Comment: May be you can look at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23039374/allow-only-numbers-into-a-input-text-box/23039938#23039938) and see if it fits to your situation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add  **onClick="*this.select();*"**

```
<input type="text" class="quantity"
  name="Quantity" 
  id="Quantity"
  onClick="this.select();"
  onkeydown='return (window.event.keyCode >= 48 && window.event.keyCode <= 57) || window.event.keyCode == 8 || window.event.keyCode == 46'
  required />
```