# Allow only numbers to be typed into a text input box

Tags: javascript

This question has been asked before back in 2011 [Allow only numbers into a input text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23039374/allow-only-numbers-into-a-input-text-box) but the final code doesn't work in my situation and I did wonder if there was an update scenario.

I am trying to stop all characters other than the numbers 0123456789 from being input.

```js
document.getElementById("text_input").addEventListener("keydown", (eventObject) => {
    
  // Add : after the first 2 chracters
  const length = eventObject.target.value.length;
  const keyCode = eventObject.keyCode;
  
  if (keyCode != 8 && length === 2) {
    eventObject.target.value += ":"
  }
  
  // Stop all characters other than 0123456789 from being input
  const charCode = (typeof eventObject.which == "number") ? eventObject.which : eventObject.keyCode
  
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;

});
```

```html
<input id="text_input" type="text" name="hours">
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason why `<input type='number'>` won't be sufficient?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number input type that takes only integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808590/number-input-type-that-takes-only-integers)

Comment: and if you wish to know more about input elements in general, the pattern attribute and form validation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#pattern

Comment: I can't use number as the input box is a time, unfortunately the software I wam using does not have a time type yet, it'll get added but not sure when. At the moment I need to find a workaround sense why I am using a text box and not time.

Comment: I would validate values after they were entered, not while typing. Maybe someone wants to copy&paste. Ctrl+V is certainly not a number, but should be allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("extra7").addEventListener("keydown", (eventObject) => {
    
  const length = eventObject.target.value.length;
  const keyCode = eventObject.keyCode;
  
    
  if (
    eventObject.key.length === 1 && eventObject.key !== '.' && isNaN(eventObject.key) && !eventObject.ctrlKey || 
    eventObject.key === '.' && eventObject.target.value.toString().indexOf('.') > -1
  ) {
    eventObject.preventDefault();
  }

});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="textfield" value="" id="extra7"/>
```